# how to pass type to a function with a call with generic type in swift

Tags: swift, generics, callback, closures

calling a function with a completion handler with generics value gave error in xcode about the generic type, the function definition is:

```
 func loadData<T: Codable>(params: parameters, completion: @escaping (resultados<T>) -> Void) {
    let request = requestManager()
    request.post(params: params, with: {result in
        switch result{
        case .success(let data):
            do {
                let mydata = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(.datos(Dato: mydata))
            }
            catch{
                completion(.error(Error: error))
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.error(Error: error))
        }
    })
}
```

where resultados is enum like this:

```
    enum resultados<T>{
    case datos(Dato: T)
    case error(Error: Error)
    }
```

the function makes a request and decode the response bases on T type. but when making the call to the function how is posible to espicify the generic type because this code not work:

```
let dat = dataLoader()
dat.loadData<T:productResponse>(params: parameters.Endpoint(endpoint: end), completion:{ result in
            switch result{
            case .datos(let Dato):
                self.mydata = Dato as? productResponse
                self.stopanAnimation()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showResult", sender: self)
                }
            case .error(let error):
                self.stopanAnimation()
            }
        })
```

since xcode say 
[image]
and removing T to leave like this `dat.loadData<productResponse>(params: parameters.Endpoint(endpoint: end), completion:{ result in`
then xcode says

> Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

EDIT:
the whole point of this question is to try to compiler be able to infer type or a lest a way to say what's the type of the enum with generics value, since the function parameters does not have the type of the callback inside the enum is not posible to infer, a code that does not work but to express what i mean.

```
func loadData<T:Codable>(params: parameters,completion: @escaping (resultados<T>) -> Void)
```

since resultados is enum with a generics conforming to codable. i would like to call the function in a way that i can pass the decoding type. something like this

```swift
    let dec = dataLoder()
    dec.dataLoader<T:productResponse>(params: parameters,completion: { result in)
result in the completion is another enum with this format:

    enum resultados<T>{
    case datos(Dato: T)
    case error(Error: Error)
    }
so i have to swich the enum and obtain the decoded value. guess this is not posible in swift with the above o any other way for the compiler reconigze it.
```

Comment: You should pay attention for Swift naming convention `ProductResponse` and use lowerCase for your instance variables and constants

Comment: Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a specific handler function:

```
func resultadosHandler(resultados: resultados<productResponse>) { // productResponse is the type you expect
    switch resultados {
    case .datos(let dato): print(dato)
    case .error(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

Pass it to loader function:

```
dat.loadData(params: parameters.Endpoint(endpoint: end), completion: resultadosHandler)
```

Or if you prefer, you can use it inline mode like this:

```
loadData(params: parameters.Endpoint(endpoint: end)) { (resultados: resultados<productResponse>) in
    switch resultados {
    case .datos(let dato): print(dato)
    case .error(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace prints with the correct implementation!